# MongoDB dependency for spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, maven, dependency-injection

I am a beginner to mongodb and spring, so I apologise if the question is silly.

I want to use mongodb in my spring application. I created a maven project, what dependencies do I need to add in my pom.xml file.

I can see some jars like **spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb** is added but can find no explantions about it. What does it do exactly?

Comment: Google? https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+boot+mongodb lots of resources and sample repositories.

Comment: look into the official resource page http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/